# unable to upgrade/uninstall current version of python

Tags: ubuntu, python, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade the default version of python on ubuntu 16.04.
I have already run
`sudo apt-get install python3.5` command. The result is like below...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.5 is already the newest version (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

I also tried to uninstall current version of python. But it didn't work.

Now, how can I upgrade python??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your aim with the upgrade?   Generally, Ubuntu's system update is built in Python - so messing with Python 2 or 3 may potentially cause trouble in that realm. I'd advice to keep it safe... i.e. leave alone unless you have a really urgent need for the very latest options AND know how to deal with any consequences.

Comment: Why not just install the newer version? You can leave python3.5 on your system as it is.

Comment: So far I know that there is some difference in coding in different version of python. As I am in  learning stage, I become confused in some cases. That's why I wanted to upgrade to python3 as my book from where I am learning is in python3.

Comment: @user3169, hello. In my system, there is only python2.7. But after running python3.5 installation command it showed me that python3.5 is already a newer version.

Comment: How did you install 16.04? Full install or upgrade from an earlier version? Full install from live CD should include python 3.5, or get it from Software Updates.

Comment: Full install from live usb. But when I check the version of python it shows only python 2.7